# How to insert the "X is a subset of Y, but is not equal to Y" symbol?

Tags: symbols

How can I insert the "X is a subset of Y, but is not equal to Y" symbol? I have tried using `$\subsetneq$`, as in `$X \subsetneq Y$`, but this yields the error message:

```
Undefined control sequence.
```

There is no problem using `$\subseteq$`.

Code:

```
\title{Subset-Not-Equal-To}
\author{}
\date{}

\documentclass[8pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

$X \subsetneq Y$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. I think that may be `amssymb` is the package that provides that symbol, but there is no option to see what you actually loaded.

Comment: @Manuel: Added. Please see above.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to load the `amssymb` package. Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Type ``\verb|$A \subsetneq  B$|'' to get ``$A \subsetneq B$''.

Type ``\verb|$A \subsetneqq B$|'' to get ``$A \subsetneqq B$''.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]